# How to configure a magento 1.7.2 multistore with PayPal multi accounts ?

Tags: magento, paypal

I have a magento 1.7.2 running in multistore mode, how can I set a paypal IPN for each site? (The two sites use different paypal account.) 
Looks like I can set the paypal IPN only on the default configuration. 
Any tips? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/79479/

tested and running in my site
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are talking about IPN, which means Instant Payent Notification? It is not necessary to configure anything about IPN in Magento.

When sending a transaction to PayPal Magento tells PayPal which URL to use for IPN. This URL is store specific and overwrites any settings done in your PayPal account. So what you have to do ist change PayPal API Crendentials for each store in Magento, which can be done by choosing the current config section.

Comment: Looks like I can set the paypal account (API or email) only on the default configuration.

Comment: You have to uncheck the "Use Default" Checkboxes beside the fields to enter the API Crendentials. After that the disabled inputs will become active and you are able to enter different credentials for the current store or website.

Answer (score 1):

Create another module with admin configuration of the other emails you want to support 
and extend the model

```
Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard
```

and override the method

```
public function getConfig()
```

to set your logic for switching the config ( paypal email accounts )

Comment: Sorry could you be more specific?

Comment: the second answer or the one you have posted earlier, it depends on store view to change configuration, what i have told you above is to CREATE magento module and Extend Paypal standard model and override this method to set whatever payment emails you want to use ! that is already specific i dont know how to explain more :)

Comment: This would be very useful when you wont have multiple stores